# GWT DeckLayoutPanel UiBinder code

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I was trying to specify usage of a DeckLayoutPanel (not Dock...) in UiBinder using `<g:layer>` tags, but that didn't seem to work. Does anyone have proper usage of this component when using inside .ui.xml?

I don't see it documented in javadoc at least or anywhere on the web for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<g:layer>` tags are only for `LayoutPanel`. `DeckLayoutPanel` manages the layout of its children, so you use it just like any `HasWidgets`: add child widgets as direct child elements.

You can see it used in the [MobileWebApp sample's Tablet UI](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.0/samples/mobilewebapp/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/mobilewebapp/client/tablet/MobileWebAppShellTablet.ui.xml#95).

Comment: that was it, had a hard time finding an example for it, and assumed <g:layer> incorrectly. The javadoc really needs to show uibinder example.

Comment: The rule of thumb of GWT javadoc is that if there's nothing special to be said, then nothing is said; rather than duplicating doc that then needs to be kept in sync, etc. Note that nothing is said in `SplitLayoutPanel`'s javadoc, because it's no different from `DockLayoutPanel`, except for what's pointed out (dimensions are all in pixels)

Answer (score 1):

[plusplayground](https://code.google.com/p/plusplayground/source/browse/trunk/src/com/real8/plusplayground/client/shell/PlusPlaygroundShellViewImpl.ui.xml?spec=svn22&r=22) library seems to use DeckLayoutPanel with UiBinder. I've not used this one, not sure if it's working or not. Having said that, you haven't mentioned about any specific issues with that.